# Rails combine two relations to one result

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have a Dogs and Owners tables
I want to have a result in which the resulting objects have fields of the dog and the owner, so I can use this object later on, convert to json, etc, without needed to query the database again or hit the cache

so if I have `Dog.collie`, and each dog has an `id`, `breed`,`age` and `owner_id`, and each Owner has `id`, `name` -

I want to create a new object with dogs id, breed and the owner name

`Dog.joins(:owner).collie` would return a list of dog objects, and I want to do `dog.owner`, It would hit the cache. If I convert this to json, the owner name is missing

on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields it says I can return instances of the model with specific fields.

How can I return an object with 3 fields - 2 of the dog and 1 of the owner (obviously without defining such object, but let Rails do it)

Comment: Look at this link for all possible options http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: Please post more code examples and some psuedo code as to what you are looking to do.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: I'll try to explain, I know rails can do this, I just don't know how to call it

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`Dog.includes(:owner)`

But if all you want is the name then you can delegate to the owner

```
Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :name, to: :owner, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Which will allow you to do

```
@dog = Dog.first
@dog.owner_name => 'Bob'
```

Comment: yes, but after that I want to return the result as a json, so I need everything in the same hash/object

Comment: Ok, then either do as bekicot says or overwrite the `to_json` method

Answer (score 0):

What about.

```
class Dog
  belongs_to :owner
end

dogs = Dog.all

dogs.to_json(:include => :owner)
```